# Handling Mixed-Frequency time series data for Feature Selection

Tags: random-forest, feature-selection, lasso, importance, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I'm currently working on a project where I aim to apply LASSO regularization and conduct variable importance analysis on WTI crude oil prices. My challenge is dealing with datasets that have different frequencies. For instance, some variables like the dollar index are available as daily prices, whereas others like production levels are on a monthly basis.

I'm seeking advice on the best practices to transform and align these datasets to ensure the accuracy and effectiveness of the LASSO model. Specifically, I'm looking for insights on:

Data Aggregation vs. Interpolation: Should I aggregate the daily data to match the monthly frequency, or interpolate the monthly data to daily frequency? Which approach is generally more reliable in this context?

Impact on Model Performance: How do these transformations affect the performance and interpretability of LASSO regularization in time series analysis?

Best Practices for Variable Selection: Given the mixed-frequency nature of the data, are there specific considerations I should keep in mind for variable selection and importance analysis in the context of LASSO?

Examples or Case Studies: If anyone has experience or knows of case studies where similar challenges were addressed, could you share how these issues were tackled?

Any insights, references, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. My goal is to ensure the most accurate and reliable analysis possible, given the constraints of mixed-frequency data.